# What is meant by op = "" in this code?

Tags: python, variables

```
def three():
    op = ""      
    num = int(input("Input a number:"))
    while num > 0:
        r = num % 2
        num = num // 2
        op = str(r) + op  
    print (op)
```

- Could someone please explain line two of the code as it appears to not be setting anything?
- Also, could someone also explain what the second bottom line is doing?

Comment: "op" is probably short for "operand"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`op` is just an initially empty string (line 2) which gets prepended by the string representation of `r` inside the loop (2nd last line).

Say the number chosen is 5. These are the iterations of the loop:

1. r = 5%2 = 1

   num = 5//2 = 2

   op = "1"
2. r = 2%2 = 0

   num = 2//2 = 1

   op = "0" + "1" = "01"
3. r = 1%2 = 1

   num = 1//2 = 0

   op = "1" + "01" = "101"

Overall the loop makes a string which is the binary representation of the number entered.

Comment: Eoin can you please reword that as i have no idea by what you mean!

Comment: You're welcome, I just hope this wasn't homework ;)

Comment: haha errrr.... i have to say i can't disagree with that statement although you didn't do exactly what was need though

Answer (score 0):

op needs to be declared as a variable before it's used in the while loop; otherwise it would have a syntax error.  Remove that first line and see.

It's assigned "" because later on it gets added to (or rather, replaced with a new piece of text and its current value at the end).  So just doing

```
op = None
```

would not have worked (you cannot add a str and None)

The second bottom line concatenates; r needs to be converted to a string (because it's an int), and so it ends up prepending the value of r as a string to op.

Comment: Python doesn't have variable declarations, and there's no syntactic problem with using undefined variables.

Comment: when i run the prgram it is fine and what does"operand" mean and do?

Comment: Dietrich: I should have been more specific - it's a NameError.

Comment: I'd have thought it would give you an `UnboundLocalError`, not a `NameError`.

Comment: It's not giving me any errors its working fine. i just don't understand the code. could someone go through what's it's doing please! Also, the output isn't making much sense either.

Comment: @thatcoolkid like `num` and `r`, `op` is just a name. The fact that it is called `op` doesn't affect the program at all - it could equally be called `fred` (except that the particular name should *hopefully* be helpful to humans - `op` is potentially not the best choice).